# How can I hide or add a BarButtonItem dynamically when I change the current ViewController?

Tags: swift

I want to add a ***BarButtonItem*** every time the user jumps to the ***Controller*** and remove it dynamically when the user selects another ViewController in the navigation bar.

---

```
    let filterBtn = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(action(sender:)))
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = filterBtn
}
```

---

I added two ***BarButtonItem*** in my ***UIStoryBoard*** and now I want to add one more button dynamically but only if the ***ViewController*** is selected like shown above.

It it possible to do it like this? I appreciate any input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, *navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems* is an array and you can remove/append elements. I'll suggest you to try removing "humburger" button item and adding the new one when *DocumentationViewController* is presented.

```
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems?.popLast()
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems?.append(filterBtn)
```

Comment: I don´t want to remove the other 2 buttons. Your suggestion with ***navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems?.append(filterBtn)*** works fine but how can I remove it after I select another ViewController?

Comment: I need the hamburger and info button every where.

Comment: Then simply append the button using navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems?.append(filterBtn) and remove it when DocumentationScreen is not presented